# Package not found while compiling my document

Tags: errors, paralist

The package `paralist.sty` gave me a problem (as seen in the image below):

[image: p]

This occurred every time I compile my document, please can you provide a feedback?

Comment: Well, [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx); without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe) it's very unlikely to get a proper answer, please edit your question so you can provide the source of your problem to us.

Comment: Since [`paralist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paralist) is available from CTAN and is distributed with TeX Live and MiKTeX, you probably have a minimal distribution that doesn't include it. See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Answer (score 1):

The source is, for example, here:

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/paralist/